# Windows redirection to a new Network Folder (from \\OldDirectory to \\NewDirectory)

Tags: windows, redirection, hosts

We have relocated our files to a new folder (from \\oldfolder\... to \\newfolder\...). I would like to know if on windows it is possible to redirect all the request to the new path (because we have a lot of word, excel, powerpoint, bat files that link to this folder).

PS I have no access to NAS/Server.

Edit: I have a solution with the hosts file of windows by adding:

"XX.XXX.XX.XXX oldfolder OLDFOLDER"

The ping test redirects me to the right folder, but when I try to go to the windows explorer folder : I get a message "asking me to identify myself, but my username and password don't work" or "there is no folder"

Edit2: it looks like Windows explorer goes to the oldfolder. But TortoiseSVN it's OK with Hosts edit.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not identify (and authorize) other hosts with their IP adress, so editing the HOSTS file is no way near a solution.

It is possible to add another named listener to your new file server:

```
 HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNSCache\Parameters\AlternateComputerNames
```

Then you just point the DNS name (FQDN) of OLDSERVER to NEWIPADRESS.

The "best practice" here is to avoid named UNC paths and just use domain based DFS. When using DFS, UNC to a server just does not exist.